# P39 never showed up in src

Tags: python, pip, repository, virtualenvwrapper

When I install

```
pip install -e git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/p39/lib-p39.git@de5622dcf0b9a084f9b0a34cdd1d932026904370#egg=p39
```

my program is able to find the needed files.

However, if I want to make changes locally and install the same library with

```
pip install -e ~/Projects/Work_Projects/BP/lib-p39
```

I got the following traceback

```
Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/infinity/Projects/Work_Projects/Budget_Propane/clients-budgetpropane-com/zoneclient/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/dashboard/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappelli/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grappellifit/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dajaxice/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/p39/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paypal/standard/ipn/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/guardian/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/userena/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap_ui/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/captcha/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)
/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/zoneclient/dashboard.html (File does not exist)

Traceback:
File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  103.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  78.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_template
  54.             return loader.select_template(template)
File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/p39-1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in select_template
  194.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(not_found))

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /dashboard
Exception Value: zoneclient/dashboard.html
```

Here's what I have in `lib-p39` ripo:

```
MANIFEST.in  p39 p39.egg-info  README.md  setup.py
```

In fact, p39 is installed in `~/.virtualenv/p39-1/src` with the first command, but if I remove `p39` from src and use the second command, then `src` has no longer `p39` directory.

```
Obtaining file:///home/infinity/Projects/Work_Projects/Budget_Propane/webservice-integration
Installing collected packages: p39
  Found existing installation: p39 0.0.1
    Uninstalling p39-0.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled p39-0.0.1
  Running setup.py develop for p39
Successfully installed p39
```

So roughly, with the second command `p38.egg-link` is installed in `site-packages`, but `p38` is never installed in `src`.

```
from distutils.core import setup

try:
    import setuptools
except ImportError:
    pass

    install_requires = [
    ]

    setup(name='p39',
          # Keep version in sync with up/__init__.py, Install section
          # of README.rst, and USER_AGENT in scripts/pypi-install.
          version='0.0.1',
          author='test test',
          author_email='test@test.com',
          description='',
          include_package_data=True,
          long_description=open('README.md').read(),
          license='',
          url='',
          packages=[
              'p39',
              'p39.api',
              'p39.api.views',
              'p39.conf',
              'p39.formats',
              'p39.management',
              'p39.management.commands',
              'p39.migrations',
              'p39.templatetags',
              'p39.tests',
              'p39.views',
          ],
         #scripts=['scripts/cmd-line'],
          install_requires=install_requires,
```

Any help?

### UPDATE

```
workon p39-1
cd ~/Projects/Work_Projects/BP/
git clone git@gitlab.com:p38/lib-p39.git de5622dcf0b9a084f9b0a34cdd1d932026904370
cd de5622dcf0b9a084f9b0a34cdd1d932026904370
pip install -e .
```

Be aware that there is no requirement for that project.

```
(p39-1) ┌─╼ [~/.virtualenvs]
└────╼ cd p39-1/
bin  include  lib  local  pip-selfcheck.json  share  src
(p39-1) ┌─╼ [~/.virtualenvs/p39-1]
└────╼ ls src/
pip-delete-this-directory.txt  python-dploy
(p39-1) ┌─╼ [~/.virtualenvs/p39-1]
└────╼
```

Answer (score 0):

First clone the source

```
../my/dir> git clone git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/p39/lib-p39.git
```

then install

```
../my/dir> cd lib-p39
../my/dir/lib-p39> pip install -e .
../my/dir/lib-p39> pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The documentation might also be helpful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/reusable-apps/

Comment: I will show you exactly what I have done so far in an update. Let me three minutes and you will see